# Due to LINQ Retrieving of Record data's i have this error: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
private void getUserLoginDepartment(string AccessID, string UserPROFid)
        {
            try
            {
                DBWPAccountRecordsDataContext DBACCOUNT = new DBWPAccountRecordsDataContext();
                var query = (from i in DBACCOUNT.WP_UserAccessPorts
                             join
                                 z in DBACCOUNT.WP_Departments on i.AccessPortID equals z.Dept_ID
                             where i.AccessPortID == AccessID && i.ProfileUser_ID == UserPROFid
                             select new
                             {
                                 PORT1 = i.AccessPoint1,
                                 PORT2 = i.AccessPoint2,
                                 PORT3 = i.AccessPoint3,
                                 PORT4 = i.AccessPoint4,
                                 DEPT = z.Dept_DESC,
                                 DEPTPORT = z.Dept_PortNo
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (query.PORT1.ToString() != null || query.PORT1.ToString() != string.Empty)
                { Session["Port1"] = query.PORT1; }
                else { Session["Port1"] = ""; }
                if (query.PORT2.ToString() != null || query.PORT2.ToString() != string.Empty)
                { Session["Port2"] = query.PORT2; }
                else { Session["Port2"] = ""; }
                if (query.PORT3.ToString() != null || query.PORT3.ToString() != string.Empty)
                { Session["Port3"] = query.PORT3; }
                else { Session["Port3"] = ""; }
                if (query.PORT4.ToString() != null || query.PORT4.ToString() != string.Empty)
                { Session["Port4"] = query.PORT4; }
                else { Session["Port4"] = ""; }                
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
```

The Error occures when i reach break point 1st IF Statement the record on my database shows that its not empty which its value is "WebAdmin" but then suppost to be it should pick it up and store it to the Session["PORT1"] that i have made is there something i missed or i'm doing it wrong on my linq Query. NOTE:*This is an ASP.NET C# Application

EDIT 10/2/2013 0420PM:
It's still an Error After using that method sir.

[image]

Comment: *Due to LINQ ... i have ... NullReferenceException* Damnit, LINQ! You had one job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `query.PORT1` for `null` before calling `ToString` on it, you can use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)  to check both conditions. Before checking query.PORT1 you need to check if `query` is `null` or not. You also need to use && instead of or operator as `||` will cause the right side of or operator to be evaluated if left is `false` and on right side calling ToString on null will again through exception.

```
if (query != null && query.PORT1 != null && query.PORT1.ToString() != string.Empty)
                { Session["Port1"] = query.PORT1; }
```

Using IsNullOrEmpty

```
if(query != null &&  !String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.PORT1))
{
   Session["Port1"] = query.PORT1;
}
```

Comment: Can put break point and debug to check if query is null or query.PORT1 is null. Did you try using following statement and got null exeception> if(query != null &&  !String.IsNullOrEmpty(query.PORT1))

Comment: i see the problem is that i didn't notice things at all sorry its ok now sir thanks both..

Answer (score 1):

1) you should check `query` for `null` when you use `FirstOrDefault`

2) you need to check each PORTX for `null`

3) use `string.IsNullOrEmpty( )` to check if the string of PORTX is `null`

```
var query = ( ... ).FirstOrDefault( );
if( query != null )
{
    if( query.PORT1 != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( query.PORT1.ToString( ) ) )
    {
    }
    else { ... }
}
```

Comment: @Oblivious7 do you really check the query for null? In the picture with the exception i don't see a check for null

Comment: i see the problem is that i didn't notice things at all sorry its ok now sir thanks both.. sorry i couldn't give you a check anymore so i give you a up of "useful answer"